Combining multiple outcomes/measurements in meta-analysis
I am conducting a meta-analysis with 12 studies. 4 studies use multiple ways to measure the same outcome or measure the same outcome at different time points. In any case, the outcomes/measurements in those studies are dependent.
Here is how I am currently dealing with the situation:
I have a separate R code for every study. Here, I calculate the effect sizes present in each study. If multiple effect sizes exist per study, I combine the effect sizes in the end with the agg-function of the MAd package (based on Borenstein: https://meta-analysis.com/download/Meta-analysis%20Studies%20with%20multiple%20subgroups%20or%20outcomes.pdf). I need to specify a correlation to do that. I use the conservative option and choose r=1.
In the end, I get one effect size and its variance per study. I then combine this data manually using the rma function in Metafor. This is also where I am conducting subgroup analyses/meta-regressions (I know I have to be careful with the interpretation as only 12 studies are included). Moderators are always at the study level (related to the intervention design) and not at the individual effect size level.
I intend to do a sensitivity analysis, changing the correlation to smaller values in the few cases where multiple measurements/outcomes exist, to see whether my results are robust.
During my research, I stumbled upon multivariate/multilevel meta-analysis. Is my approach also acceptable to deal with the situation (I tried to follow Borenstein et al., 2021 recommendations) or in what ways are those superior to mine?
Thank you very much for your help!!
